# Show that the variance of the portfolio market portfolio is function of the betas of its consituents

Tags: portfolio-optimization, statistics, modern-portfolio-theory, finance-mathematics, statistical-finance

Let us assume that the market portfolio consists of n assets.
Given that the return of the market portfolio can be written as $r_m = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j$, we have that $\sigma^2_m = E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2$, but how do I show that $$E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m)$$?
If I show that the equation above is true, than I can claim that $$E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j\beta\sigma^2_m$$

Comment: Please put this together with your other question and put some more effort in that question itself. What did you try? Please show your work.